# How to access getColumnNames from JSP in EL?

Tags: java, sql, jstl, el

I'm using the JSTL SQL tag library to perform small SQL queries from within a JSP.

I normally retrieve the query results in EL by using rowsByIndex and then iterating over the returned collection:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${myQuery.rowsByIndex}">
    <p>${row[0]}, ${row[1]}, ${row[2]}, ${row[3]}</p>
</c:forEach>>
```

I want to do something similar for the column names.

I see that there is a method on the result interface:

```
public String[] getColumnNames();
```

and I'm trying to figure out how to access this from EL.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
...
  <table>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${helloQuery.getColumnNames}">
            <th><c:out value="${columnName}" /></th>
        </c:forEach>
    <tr>
  </table>
...
```

But no joy..

Comment: I've found the answer as I was typing up the question.
I don't feel like wasting the effort of typing it and maybe it will benefit someone. (My reputation isn't high enough to post this yet - so I'm adding it as a comment)

It is done the following way:

    <c:forEach var="columnName" items="**${helloQuery.columnNames}**"> 

The `get` falls away.

I'm curious as to the capitilization being removed as well though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) relies on the [Javabeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) and its naming conventions when it comes to accessing properties. You basically only need to specify the property name (even though it's virtual) and EL will turn it into a getter call when the value needs to be returned, or into a setter call when the value needs to be set (in JSF `#{}` syntax only though).

So, `${helloQuery.getColumnNames}` is basically trying to invoke `getGetColumnNames()` method on the class represented by `${helloQuery}`. But there is none and this would result in a `PropertyNotFoundException`. You need to change it to `${helloQuery.columnNames}` in order to invoke the `getColumnNames()` method.